# Should I Replicate Data If Data size is huge in Microservice Architecture?

Tags: design-patterns, service, architecture, microservices, grpc

Consider company like Amazon, Flipkart.

They shows our order history means they have Order Microservice and Item Detail Microservice.

So Whenever I open my order list, these sites fetch data from order microservice with list of my transaction status against the order. My best guess is they keep maintain order status against transaction Id in Order Table, that is replicated data because same data exist in Payment/Transaction Microservice also.

Can Any one tell me If this transaction data is exponentially increasing in system, did it make sense to store it in Order Microservice also.

Or My guess is wrong in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the main question, data should not be replicated just because the data size is huge in a microservice architecture. Replication can be considered a tool to use in circumstances where having another copy of the data is useful. Ex:

1. High availability is needed across restarts (zero-downtime).
2. Data is needed in different regions with low latency (cachine).
3. If a flood hits the location where data is stored (disaster recovery).

Most likely, transaction data is increasing linearly in the system. Exponential growth is generally unsustainable. I'm not sure how Amazon/Flipkart model their data but one way to approach the above is to build a relationship between orders, payments, and items. Ex:

1. Orders know what items they have. (list of item ID)
2. Orders know what payments have been made. (list of payment ID)

Order Structure: ID, Status, item IDs, payment IDs
Payment Structure: ID, Status, Amount
Item Structure: ID, Name, Amount

It may be the case that Order, Payment, and Item are separate microservices, but IDs can still be used to fetch relevant data from each microservice as needed.